# Плавная прокрутка к якорю без jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть отличный скрипт плавной прокрутки на jQuery.

```
var $page = $('html, body');
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
    $page.animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 400);
    return false;
});
```

Как можно отобразить на чистом JS?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/javascript-smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery/19808153

Comment: @Shperung отметьте пожалуйста другой мой ответ как принятый, в современных условиях это уже не актуально, только вводит людей в заблуждение

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```js
// собираем все якоря; устанавливаем время анимации и количество кадров
const anchors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')),
      animationTime = 300,
      framesCount = 20;

anchors.forEach(function(item) {
  // каждому якорю присваиваем обработчик события
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // убираем стандартное поведение
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // для каждого якоря берем соответствующий ему элемент и определяем его координату Y
    let coordY = document.querySelector(item.getAttribute('href')).getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
    
    // запускаем интервал, в котором
    let scroller = setInterval(function() {
      // считаем на сколько скроллить за 1 такт
      let scrollBy = coordY / framesCount;
      
      // если к-во пикселей для скролла за 1 такт больше расстояния до элемента
      // и дно страницы не достигнуто
      if(scrollBy > window.pageYOffset - coordY && window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset < document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // то скроллим на к-во пикселей, которое соответствует одному такту
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollBy);
      } else {
        // иначе добираемся до элемента и выходим из интервала
        window.scrollTo(0, coordY);
        clearInterval(scroller);
      }
    // время интервала равняется частному от времени анимации и к-ва кадров
    }, animationTime / framesCount);
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#head1">head 1</a>
  <li><a href="#head2">head 2</a>
  <li><a href="#head3">head 3</a>
  <li><a href="#head4">head 4</a>
</ul>

<h2 id="head1">heading 1</h2>
<h2 id="head2">heading 2</h2>
<h2 id="head3">heading 3</h2>
<h2 id="head4">heading 4</h2>
```

Answer (score 27):

Есть еще стандартный способ плавной прокрутки [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]')

for (let anchor of anchors) {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    const blockID = anchor.getAttribute('href').substr(1)
    
    document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start'
    })
  })
}
```

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#head1">head 1</a>
  <li><a href="#head2">head 2</a>
  <li><a href="#head3">head 3</a>
  <li><a href="#head4">head 4</a>
</ul>

<h2 id="head1">heading 1</h2>
<h2 id="head2">heading 2</h2>
<h2 id="head3">heading 3</h2>
<h2 id="head4">heading 4</h2>
```

Comment: почему может не работать?

Answer (score 10):

Кросплатформенный вариант:

`currentYPosition` - определяет текущее положение скрола

`elmYPosition` - определяет положение элемента

`smoothScroll` - собственно сама функция.

```
function currentYPosition() {
    // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
    // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
        return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
    if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
    return 0;
}


function elmYPosition(eID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
    var y = elm.offsetTop;
    var node = elm;
    while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
        node = node.offsetParent;
        y += node.offsetTop;
    } return y;
}


function smoothScroll(eID) {
    var startY = currentYPosition();
    var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
    var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
    if (distance < 100) {
        scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
    }
    var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
    if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
    var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
    var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
    var timer = 0;
    if (stopY > startY) {
        for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
            setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
            leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
        } return;
    }
    for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
        setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
        leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
    }
}
```

Ответ [взят отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/javascript-smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery)

Упрощенная версия, когда надо просто проскролить к определенной позиции

```
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}
```

Ответ [взят отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)

Comment: У вас в коде есть конструкция if (self.pageYOffset) , разве не можна if (pageYOffset)  ?

Comment: Это не мой код, это из ответа на англ. версии. Фишка в том, чтобы это правильно сработало во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 3):

```
var nodeObj = document.querySelector('.button-node');

nodeObj.scrollIntoView({
   behavior: "smooth",
   block:    "start" 
});
```

Comment: такой ответ уже есть.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const anim = (sel, duration) => {
  let to = document.querySelector(sel).getBoundingClientRect().top,
      temp;

  return (sel) => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(temp); 
      var start = performance.now(); 
      var from = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;        
      requestAnimationFrame(function step(timestamp) {
          var progress = (timestamp - start) / duration;
          1 <= progress && (progress = 1);
          window.scrollTo(0, from + to * progress | 0);  
          1 > progress && (temp = requestAnimationFrame(step))
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const scrollWindow = () => {
// На сколько пикселей будет прокручиваться страница
    let scrolled;
    let timer;
//  Через сколько действие будет повторяться

//  Получаем еэлемент через ID
    document.getElementById(IDelemen).onclick = function(){
        scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
// Определяем место положение скролла на странице
    
// запуск функции    
        scrollToTop(); 
    }
//  Сама функции
    function scrollToTop(){
// Если положение скрола не вверху страницы
        if (scrolled > 0) {
//Скролим вверх 
            window.scrollTo(0, scrolled);
// Скроллим веерх (отнимаем кол-во пикселей от текущего значения) 
            scrolled = scrolled - 50; //100 - скорость прокрутки
            timer = setTimeout(scrollToTop, 200); //время повторения
// Через какое время запустить повторную проверку
// Повторение будет продолжаться, пока scrolled не станет - 0
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
//Останавливаем по достижению верха страницы
        }
    }
}
// Вызов функкции
scrollWindow ();

// Регулировать плавность (прокрутной и повторением)
```