# Как при событии scroll сделать прокрутку до необходимого блока?

Tags: javascript

Нужен способ на нативном js? 
Функция плавного скролла у меня есть

```js
const anim = (sel, duration) => {
  let to = document.querySelector(sel).getBoundingClientRect().top,
      temp;
 
  return (sel) => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(temp); 
      var start = performance.now(); 
      var from = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;        
      requestAnimationFrame(function step(timestamp) {
          var progress = (timestamp - start) / duration;
          1 <= progress && (progress = 1);
          window.scrollTo(0, from + to * progress | 0);  
          1 > progress && (temp = requestAnimationFrame(step))
      });
  }

}
```

И она работает например если вешаю на кнопку, но когда ставлю ее на событие скролла

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", anime(".last-block", 1000), false);
```

то страница начинает плавно подниматься вверх и бесконечно тресется.

Comment: и как вы хотите чтобы работало с конечном итоге?

Comment: дело в том, что `window.scrollTo` который находится внутри функции `anim` вызывает у документа событие `scroll`, а событие `scroll` вызывает функцию `anim` получается бесконечный вызов скролла, вот и трясется.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц  чтобы при попытке скролла,  страница сама  автоматически прокручивалась до следующего или предыдущего блока, в зависимости от того вверх скролят или вниз

Comment: щас писать некогда, могу только навести....[вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676303/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-jquery) примерно то, что вам нужно (только нужно поработать над саммим событием, а так же как то нужно выбирать след блок или предыдущий)

Comment: @Vladimir другие методы не подходят, потому что на айпаде тоже должно работать. В anim ставил рекурсию - все равно ни то..

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц  что только не предпринял, не получается..

Comment: Давайте уточним, вы хотите крутить колесико вниз и прокручивать атоматом до следующей секции? ну и вверх аналогично? Может я что-то не так понимаю, но разве это удобно?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц так нужно по ТЗ, Залил на gitpages brushhttps://bembolat.github.io/onpoint (сделайте разрешение для iPad (1024x768)