# Как реализовать анимацию для скрола на чистом js?

Tags: javascript

Как можно реализовать плавный скролл?

```
Window.scroll(0,500);
```

Comment: Что значит **анимация** для скролла?

Comment: Вообще не понятно о чем речь...

Comment: Наверное, под анимацией тс имел ввиду плавный скролл

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Плавная прокрутка к якорю без jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676303/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%8f%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo({top: 500, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})
```